# How can I map a form to two different methods in controller using RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web

So my Spring MVC project home page has two input fields within a form.

The user can enter the roll number or name.

Jsp

```
<form action="search" method="GET" >
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <input  type="text" id="regNo" name="regNo" size="30" maxLength="50" "></input> or 
            <input  id="studentName" type="text" size="30" maxLength="50" "></input>
</form>
```

In my controller, I have two methods mapped to two input fields.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStudent(String regNo, ModelMap model){

        return "A";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String searchStudentByName(String studentName, ModelMap model){

        return "B";
    }
```

Since both the input fields are String, I don't know how can I map them to two different methods in controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want something like this :

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET,value = "/search/r/regNo={regNo}")
public String getStudent(@PathVariable String regNo){

}
```

for studentName :

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET,value = "/search/s/studentName={studentName}")
public String getStudent(@PathVariable String studentName){

}
```

then you need to add both request in different `form tag`, & in action tag provide :

if `regNo` send :

```
/search/r/
```

for `studentName` :

```
/search/s/
```

Jsp :

```
<form action="search/r" method="GET" >
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <input  type="text" id="regNo" name="regNo" size="30" maxLength="50" "></input> 
            <input type="submit" name="approve" value="RegNo" />
</form>    
<form action="search/s" method="GET" >
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <input  id="studentName" type="text" size="30" maxLength="50" "></input>
            <input type="submit" name="approve" value="StudentName" />
</form>
```

**OR Second way to do so :**

```
<form action="search" method="GET" >
                <input  type="text" id="regNo" name="regNo" size="30" maxLength="50" "></input> 
                <input  id="studentName" type="text" size="30" maxLength="50" "></input>

                <input type="submit" name="regno" value="regno" />
                <input type="submit" name="studentName" value="studentName" />
</form>
```

controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "regno" })
public String getRegno(@RequestParam String regno) {

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "studentName" })
public String getStudent(@RequestParam String studentName) {

}
```

Post me.

Comment: I want to send regNo on one request and studentName on another request. I won't be doing both at a time.

Comment: OK just a second then wait a minute, i just update the answer.

Comment: Could you please write jsp changes as well? Thanks.

Comment: did you want multiple controller ?

Comment: In jsp, I will be bringing in javascript, where if the user starts typing in the regNo, the studentName field will be disabled and vice versa. Does Using two different form tags will open any security holes?

Comment: Nope. I prefer single controller, since the application doesn't have any heavy business logic.

Comment: If I have a single search button in common for both regNo and studentName, how can I still have single search button when I have two form tags?

Comment: that you ll have to do using JavaScript that which to send & where to send.. Use any javascript library to perform requests. That ll be better.

Comment: or you can use `multiple RequestMapping` concept with `2 form tags`, so controller will be one just use 2 form tag into `jsp`.

Comment: see http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handling-multipage-forms-with-abstractwizardformcontroller/, you will other new way for to do so

Comment: May I know how can I send requests using Javascript library. Any online examples would be helpful.

Comment: OK. I am ready to use two controllers. But now can I use single search button in UI?

Comment: In your second method, should the RequestMethod be POST? If yes, Why?

Comment: sorry by mistake i have added it, if you want to use 2 controller & 1 button then on button click call javascript function that will check which textbox has data and as per it will send ajax request to that controller. Have you got it ?

Comment: I don't know AJAX. Could you help me with an outline code. Please.

Comment: look http://www.commonj.com/blogs/2013/02/10/spring-mvc-tutorial-passing-request-parameters-via-javascript-jquery-example/, you ll get idea of ajax from it. in that one request is there, you need to check under condition. You need 2 requests, one in if true & one in if false(in else).

Comment: Hi, Could you help me in writing the AJAX condition alone. Please.

Comment: HI, sorry for late reply : see http://pastebin.com/7YGKXm9D, I have done some stuff, there can be some naming & controller name change then change it as per you.

Comment: Thanks. I was reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call and thought of sharing with you. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hmm. Have you done it ? Means solved it ? Requests working or not ?

Comment: Yeah I made the changes. But I am confused as how should my form block look in jsp when I use ajax. Because now I am using one button and two form tags

`<form action="search/s" method="GET" >
                <input  type="text" id="regNo" name="regNo" size="30" maxLength="50"></input> 
    </form>        
    <form action="search/l" method="GET" >    
                <input  type="text" id="studentName" name="studentName" size="30" maxLength="50"></input>
  </form>     
    
                <button onclick="processInput();">Search
                </button>`

Comment: Oh sorry sorry, now no need of 2 form tag, use only one form tag, because all control in hand of JavaScript so easy & chill. try by removing one form & post me what happen. I also want to know how it behave.

Comment: 1)If it is one form tag, how should my action attribute of form block look like. because in the JS we are giving two different url. 
2) In the JS, should the url be /ProjectCtxt/app/search/s or just search/s would work. My actual url would be localhost:8080/ProjectCtxt/app/search/s?regNo=123

Comment: in JS give `ProjectCtxt/app/search/s` as `url` in form action will be remain blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62173/discussion-between-user3705478-and-user3145373-).

Comment: Hi Could you please answer this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136283/why-does-this-ajax-call-doesnt-return-success-and-change-url-in-browser-after-r